# Query with different categories

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to look if there are more than one `QuestionCategory` in one day in the table `contentment`. In my case people don't need to answer in one day questions with different categories. I can make a `trigger` of this.

> **The contentmenttable:** employeeid, questionid, date, score
>
> **The questiontable:** questionid, questioncat, question
>
> Data contentmenttable: 1, 1, 11-18-2018, 4
>
> Data questiontable: 1, **Work**, How is your job? 2, **Work**, Are you happy
>   with your job?

If have something like this:

```
select c.questionid, date
from contentment c 
join question q
on c.questionid= q.questionid
group by c.questionid, date
having count(questioncat) >= 2
```

But this query is only counting `IF` a `questionid` is two times or more in this table, not if there are two `different` `questioncategories` in this table.
I use SQL Server.

So if someone wants to insert this:
`insert into contentment values (1, 2, 11-18-2018', null)` (null because employee needs to give a score)
The query needs to give this questionid and date (2 and 11-18-2018), because it is the same questioncat "work" on the same day 11-18-2018.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Why is `questioncat` in both tables?

Comment: I added some more information, hope it's clear now. Your solution also did not work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `DISTINCT`:

```
select c.questionid, date
from contentment c 
join question q
on c.questionid= q.questionid
group by c.questionid, date
having count(DISTINCT questioncat) >= 2;
             -- counting only different questioncat
```

Comment: It does not work. Maybe I first need to count the questionsid's in the table contentment and then look if there are two different questioncategories on the same day?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is hard to follow, but I think you want employees that have more than one question category in a given day.  If so:

```
select c.employeeid, c.date, count(distinct q.questioncat)
from contentment c join
     question q
     on c.questionid = q.questionid
group by c.employeeid, c.date
having count(distinct q.questioncat) >= 2;
```